# make VS have --causative verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs

Because the weather is too cold, the teacher "makes" Ken close the two doors of the classroom.

In the sentence, can I use "have" instead?

How would you use "makes' and "have" in a sentence?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **has**, instead of **have**, but then it's fine. The two sentences below have have the same meaning. The teacher does something which causes Ken to close the window, for example the teacher tell him to do so (but how exactly the teacher does this is not specified).

> The teacher **makes** Ken close the two doors of the classroom.
>
> The teacher **has** Ken close the two doors of the classroom.

In the second case you'd be using the 25th meanign listed for **to have** in the [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/have_1):

> 25 to tell or arrange for someone to do something for you

Example from the same source:

> He **had** the bouncers throw them out of the club.

Attribution: Have_1 Verb - Definition, Pictures, Pronunciation and Usage Notes | Oxford Advanced American Dictionary at OxfordLearnersDictionaries.com. Accessed April 19, 2018. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/have_1.

Answer (score 0):

Some sentences to exemplify the common usages FYI:

-Make:

- I made the clock work again.
- We made him monitor of ours.
- We made him gook to look at.

  - Have:
- I had the clock work again.( I intended to make it happen.)
- I had my leg broken.(I didn't expect or intend it to happen.)
- I had not any money left.(I owned or had sth.)